# Reverse engineering mobile vs. web APIs

Tags: api, reverse-engineering

When reverse engineering an API, is there an advantage to looking at the mobile app rather than the web client? Looking at tutorials online, it seems much more common to focus on the mobile app, and I'm curious why this is. One guess: APIs used by mobile apps can only be deprecated slowly, since people can have stale versions of the app on their phone for months. Are there other reasons to prefer reverse engineering the mobile API?

Answer (score 1):

Your guess about mobile APIs being deprecated slowly is a valid one and most significant argument in favour of choosing mobile API over web API.

Basically developers make new versions of mobile API either with new endpoints or keep old endpoints which have slightly different behavior depending on request parameters.
Regardless of the way they pick you are basicaly safe to keep your code as long as resource is alive - possibility of API change is very small.

Web APIs can change dramatically overnight because clients get new front-end code simultaneously along with API changes, i.e. API got changed along with clients.

Also quite often Web APIs provide responses which contain ready to display HTML data which is hard to digest(parse properly) sometimes.

Also it is sometime easier to reverse engineer parts of java byte code (to see the logic behind token/clientID generation) albeit it being obfuscated than trying to get understanding of obfuscated and minified javascript code.